# Samsung tablet gt-p5100 Firmware Upgrade encountred an error

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, unbricking, device-firmware, odin

Nothing will make this message Go away This is after the device turned off half way though flashing.

[image]

Things i Have done.

```
Flashed With Odin 3.09 with Stock Fimware Downloaded From [sammobile.com][2]

Tried to use kies but the device is not shown and i have reinstalled the Drivers and rebooted.
```

Note: every other Version of Odin Fails to flash to the device.

[image]

Even after a Flash the Device will still Go back to Recovery Mode.

Odin 3.12 with flash error.

[image]

Comment: In what state was the device before you attempting to flash it? What error message do you get when flashing  fails? Usually thi happens when the flashing process did not complete and can be fixed simply by flashing, ideally with a repair firmware (aka 4 files firmware)

Comment: @esQmo_ Flashing dose not fail with Odin 3.09, When i got the device i could only get into download mode how ever i didn't wait long enough for the device to charge and it turned off half way though.

Comment: Weren't you able to get in the recovery?

Comment: @esQmo_ no, now i can only get into is emergency recovery.

Comment: @esQmo_ update answer with error message i get with odin3 3.12

Comment: See that... lets try flashing with repaire firmware. Another question: were the battery charging or did you get a static battery image with no charging animation?

Comment: @esQmo_ yes i saw a battery charging but not any more.

Comment: Try flashing the files I've suggested in my answer and let us know what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it is a hardware faillure (damaged eMMC), flashing a full firmware (aka repair firmware or 4 files firmware) may solved the problem.

Download repair firmware from [here](https://firmware.gem-flash.com/index.php?a=browse&b=category&id=3201) then proceed as you did beforen but preferably try flashing with the latest version of Odin (v3.12.3 actually)

The zip password is: `www.gem-flash.com`

Remember this:

- BOOTLOADER, APBOOT = BL
- PDA = AP
- MODEM = CP
- MULTI-CSC, HOME_CSC = CSC

Comment: I used Odin3 V3.12 and got.

Comment: `<ID:0/003> DO NOT TURN OFF TARGET!!
<ID:0/003> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/003> 
<ID:0/003> There is no PIT partition.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)`

Comment: Why is it even asking for a PIT file?! Did you check that option in Settings ? Do not check ''Re-Partition''

Comment: i didn't Check "Re-Partition" https://imgur.com/a/iEUbC

Comment: Oh I think I got it: the software checks for the PIT in the device and if it can't find it, throws the error. Now see if the forlder does contain a pit file then go to the PIT tab (next the Settings tab) and load that file then try flashing again.

Comment: i just flashed the MODEM and now it works :)